# Custom Hover Legend for Morris.js Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I am looking to customize the hover legend on my stacked bar chart so it won't show labels that don't have values in a specific bar, but show up in other bars. Hopefully the picture in the link below will help clear things up. The label for march in the picture has values for only a few labels, but displays all of them.  I know I have to use the hoverCallback function, but I am not sure how to only return content for labels with data. The following is a link the morris.js webpage on bar charts: [morris.js](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/bars.html). Any suggestions on how to read the row data or possible solutions would be very helpful. Thanks for the help in advance!

Morris Graph

[image: Stacked Bar Graph]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
new Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
    { t: "a", a: 2, b: 5, c: 2 },
    { t: "b", a: 3, b: null, c: null },
    { t: "c", a: 4, b: 8, c: 12 },
    { t: "d", a: null, b: 9, c: 15 }
  ],
  xkey: 't',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  labels: ['Spotify', 'Apple', 'Uber'],
  stacked: true,
  hoverCallback: function (index, options, content, row) {
    var finalContent = $(content);
    var cpt = 0;

    $.each(row, function (n, v) {
      if (v == null) {
        $(finalContent).eq(cpt).empty();
      }
      cpt++;
    });

    return finalContent;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="bar-example"></div>
```